# I want to print only 10 results from the given data. the data i have is more than 10

Tags: python, list, for-loop, web-scraping, limit

```py
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get("https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')
price = soup.find_all('span', class_='price')

for t, p in zip(title, price):

   print("{:<60} {:<30}".format(t.get_text(strip=True), p.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Comment: Slicing? I.e., `zip(title, price)[:10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `enumerate` as a counter to stop at the right number:

```py
for index,tp in enumerate(zip(title, price)):
    if index >= 10:
        break
    t, p = tp
    print("{:<60} {:<30}".format(t.get_text(strip=True), p.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could return the first 10 prices and titles like this.

```
title = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')[:10]
price = soup.find_all('span', class_='price')[:10]

"""
SAMPLE OUTPUT
Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml                                      LBP 17,999
Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml                                   LBP 3,999
Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml                             LBP 3,999
Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L                                      LBP 10,999
Pepsi Regular 2.25L                                          LBP 10,999
Pepsi Regular Can 185ml                                      LBP 4,999
Pepsi Diet Bottle 1.25L                                      LBP 8,999
Pepsi Diet Can 185ml                                         LBP 4,999
Pepsi Regular Bottle 1.25L                                   LBP 8,999
Pepsi Diet Pet - 330Ml                                       LBP 3,999
""""
```

Comment: And since `zip` stops on the shortest iteration, you only need to do one of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the first 10 results using this way. Just add this line before for loop in your code.

```
title, price = title[0:10], price[0:10]
```